# Bootstrap UI is chaning after adding FormMethod.Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap labels and textboes and it looks good but after adding formmethod.post to the view UI is changing.

[image]

the view for first pic.

```
  @model IEnumerable<AtlanticAmerican.Data.Models.ADDS.EmailSubject>

<title>title</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

```
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <form class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Send E-Mail To</label>
                    <div data-bind="foreach: recipients">
                        <!-- ko if: itemName === 'c' || itemName === 'RSDs' || itemName === 'a' || itemName === 'b'-->

</div>
       .
       .
       .
```

the view for second pic

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("eBlast", "eBlast", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {

 @model IEnumerable<AtlanticAmerican.Data.Models.ADDS.EmailSubject>

<title>title</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

```
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <form class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Send E-Mail To</label>
                    <div data-bind="foreach: recipients">
                        <!-- ko if: itemName === 'c' || itemName === 'RSDs' || itemName === 'a' || itemName === 'b'-->

</div>
       .
       .
       .

     }
```

AM i Adding this line to the wrong place?

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("eBlast", "eBlast", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put your code in jsfilldle or any other website?

I have't used KO so I don't know what's inside if condition.


Probably you are not ending div tag in proper order.

Wrap `<div data-bind="foreach: recipients"></div>` in `<div class='col-sm-9'></div>`

```
<div class='col-sm-9'>
    <div data-bind="foreach: recipients">
        <!-- ko if: itemName === 'c' || itemName === 'RSDs' || itemName === 'a' || itemName === 'b'-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added col-sm-9 it fixed little bit now i am gonna do the sme thing rest of the labels textboes. It jus weird before i added formmethod.post it looked fine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have added this @class= "form-horizontal" and it is fixed. it looks great now.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("eBlast", "eBlast", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data",@class= "form-horizontal" }))
```